# I am having trouble adding a number to a previous number and so on

Tags: python, cumulative-sum

So I have a text file which contains a list of numbers which I want to create a running total of. I need the first number to add to the second number and then the third number to add to the newly created second value and so on...
Like this:
**Old List**
0.1
0.25
0.35
0.2
0.3
**New List**
0.35
0.7
0.9
1.2

Here is what I have so far

```
import itertools
from itertools import zip_longest

open('newfile.txt','w').writelines([ line for line in open("Test1.txt") if "WIDTH" in line])
open('newfile2.txt','w').writelines([ line for line in open("Test1.txt") if "DEPTH" in line])

with open('compiled.txt', 'w') as res, open("newfile.txt") as f1, open("newfile2.txt") as f2:
for line1, line2 in zip_longest(f1, f2, fillvalue=""):
    res.write("{} : {}\n".format(line1.rstrip(), line2.rstrip()))

for line in open("compiled.txt"):
line = line.strip(', \n')
parts = line.split(":")
category = parts[0]
value = parts[1]
category2 = parts[2]
value2 = parts[3]
total = sum([int(num) for num in value])
print (total)
```

However it gives me this error:

```
total = sum([int(num) for num in value])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am new to python so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing `value`. What does it give you?

Comment: I'm guessing you want `float(num) for num in value.split()`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you just posted the input file, I see this statement `if "WIDTH" in line`; It's hard to figure this out without the presence of your data.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the error message:

```
total = sum([int(num) for num in value])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

`num` has a value of `' '`, and you're trying to convert it to an integer with `int()`. Obviously `int(' ')` is problematic, so Python throws an error.

What this means is that you have a bug in your stripping and splitting. Your code suggests that the input file format is a little more complex than what you said. If you post the actual input file (with the colons and whatnot) I'd be happy to help debug that step.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of things wrong, so that it's hard to understand what you want & what's going on.

Firstly, I suggest that instead of complicated file operations, just paste the first 5 lines or so of your  'compiled.txt' in here as

```
numbers_string = """ 1 2 
                     3 whatever
                 """
previous_val = 0
for line in numbers_string.splitlines():
    #whatever, I assume you know what you're doing
    line = line.strip(', \n')
    parts = line.split(":")
    category = parts[0]
    value = parts[1]
    category2 = parts[2]
    value2 = parts[3]
    # Calc sum of previous total and current value:
    total = previous_val + int(value)#don't you mean float?
    previous_val= total
    print( total )
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the code you posted is a bit convoluted and it's hard to figure out what you're trying to, especially since we don't have the full data you're working with. But the answer to your specific question about just adding up the numbers from one file and writing them to another one is as follows:

```
f = open("old.txt", "r")
lines = f.read().split("\n")
f.close()

total = float(lines[0])
f = open("new.txt", "w")
for line in lines[1:]:
    total += float(line)
    f.write(str(total)+"\n")
f.close()
```